# Avoiding xml permutations with Xquery when using multiple nodes to retrieve data

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, flwor

I was wondering if someone could help me. My problem is that i'm currently using BaseX which has an XQuery editor. The problem that has come to my hand is that I have a large set of XMLs and I want to reduce them. Nevertheless, some of the information is on different nodes, and when I try to retrieve them they get permutated.

The code that I used to retrieve the data was:

```
    declare namespace tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital";
    declare namespace cfdi= "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";
    declare context item := document {  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3   http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd  http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal  http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/implocal/implocal.xsd "   xmlns:implocal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal" version="3.2" serie="PUELNR"   folio="3103" fecha="2014-08-12T19:48:57"  formaDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA   EXHIBICION" noCertificado="00001000000301760734" subTotal="221.55"  descuento="0.00" TipoCambio="1.00" Moneda="MXN" total="257.00"  tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" metodoDePago="NO IDENTIFICADO"  LugarExpedicion="MÉXICO, PUEBLA">
     <cfdi:Emisor rfc="DBM131209N41" nombre="DEUTSCHE BANK MÉXICO, SA, INST DE    BANCA MÚLTIPLE, DIVISIÓN FIDUCIARIA F/1765">
     <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="RICARDO MARGAIN ZOZAYA" noExterior="605"  colonia="SANTA ENGRACIA" municipio="SAN PEDRO GARZA GARCIA" estado="NUEVO LEÓN"  pais="MÉXICO" codigoPostal="66267" />
     <cfdi:ExpedidoEn calle="CIRCUITO JUAN PABLO II" noExterior="1936" colonia="EX. HACIENDA LA NORIA" municipio="PUEBLA" estado="PUEBLA" pais="MÉXICO"  codigoPostal="72410" />
     <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="General de Ley P. M." />
  </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="MER551201D48" nombre="MERCK SA DE CV">
    <cfdi:Domicilio calle="CALLE 5" noExterior="7" colonia="FRACC.IND.ALCE BLANCO" municipio="NAUCALPAN" estado="ESTADO DE MÉXICO" pais="MÉXICO" codigoPostal="53370" />
    </cfdi:Receptor>
     <cfdi:Conceptos>
     <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="SERVICIO" noIdentificacion="0002" descripcion="CONSUMO" valorUnitario="221.55" importe="221.55" />
     </cfdi:Conceptos>
     <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="35.45">
     <cfdi:Traslados>
      <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00" importe="35.45" />
     </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
    <implocal:ImpuestosLocales version="1.0" TotaldeRetenciones="0" TotaldeTraslados="0" />
  <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital version="1.0" UUID="c286f974-9779-4a7f-82aa-1bd2a3764bfc" FechaTimbrado="2014-08-12T20:52:48" selloCFD="dQctOu630HzV6ZOJ7LhEXoGUDl7SHc/9PTzWGc9InJLzrj3eZ30Pk5e0P2j+UHjPcDMxxrgHd9m1nyGY54hAu8hBg9LXU8ErvmuBOF6XnIMvcHGtvKqoW9PEUCtAB8NtuvFKiZ5ARWb7K4y261qN8SiEoJxZm/d856jLqagSGHo=" noCertificadoSAT="00001000000300171326" selloSAT="PXBVJ7lpB9QEqtkKEmsBKcD77P2GwXNlidxGg3/R6OTRCm7/T0Rc8QPeUSBgCVSjHKN/VRKDAtBtE9pSHY0fSUTe3z7QfmuVmE3GV52T/K0fmFAUmfG0jYQTj9gOX4Z3lb2Mx+QRV+JvQO2sSnq16qco3cdSo2+tqeHFdawkR0k=" xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" /></cfdi:Complemento>
  <cfdi:Addenda xmlns:ecfd="http://www.southconsulting.com/schemas/strict" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.southconsulting.com/schemas/strict http://www.southconsulting.com/schemas/strict/ecfd.xsd">
  </cfdi:Addenda>
</cfdi:Comprobante>}
    declare context item := document {

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:detallista="http://www.sat.gob.mx/detallista" xmlns:psgecfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/psgecfd" xmlns:ecc="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ecc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.2" folio="131556" fecha="2014-07-01T08:13:34" noCertificado="00001000000301092647" formaDePago="Pago en una sola exhibicion" subTotal="156.8966" descuento="0.00" Moneda="NAL" total="182.00" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.posadas.com/MFE http://www.posadas.com/MFE/ADDENDAPOSADASVL1.xsd" xmlns:posadas="http://www.posadas.com/MFE"  metodoDePago="TARJETA DE CREDITO" NumCtaPago="1093" LugarExpedicion="AVENIDA COSTERA MIGUEL ALEMAN ACAPULCO DE JUAREZ GUERRERO MEXICO">

    <cfdi:Emisor rfc="ASO0408178B2" nombre="HOTELES Y VILLAS POSADAS, S.A. DE C.V.">

        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="AVENIDA PASEO DE LA REFORMA" noExterior="155" noInterior="PISO 4" colonia="LOMAS DE CHAPULTEPEC I SECCION" municipio="MIGUEL HIDALGO" estado="DISTRITO FEDERAL" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="11000"/>

        <cfdi:ExpedidoEn calle="AVENIDA COSTERA MIGUEL ALEMAN" noExterior="97" colonia="FRACCIONAMIENTO CLUB DEPORTIVO" municipio="ACAPULCO DE JUAREZ" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="39690" estado="GUERRERO"/>

        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="NA"/>

    </cfdi:Emisor>

    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="MER551201D48" nombre="MERCK SA DE CV">

        <cfdi:Domicilio calle="CALLE 5 No. 7 FRACC. ALCE BLANCO" municipio="NAUCALPAN DE JUAREZ" estado="ESTADO DE MEXICO" pais="MX" codigoPostal="53370"/>

    </cfdi:Receptor>

    <cfdi:Conceptos>

        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="SERVICIO" noIdentificacion="CONSUM" descripcion="CONSUMO" valorUnitario="156.8966" importe="156.8966"/>

    </cfdi:Conceptos>

    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="25.1034">

        <cfdi:Traslados>

            <cfdi:Traslado tasa="16.00" importe="25.1034" impuesto="IVA"/>

        </cfdi:Traslados>

    </cfdi:Impuestos>  <cfdi:Complemento>

    <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" FechaTimbrado="2014-07-01T08:15:15" UUID="8a4f1be7-bdcb-4b22-b144-b3e41dd92e69" version="1.0"/>

  </cfdi:Complemento>

<cfdi:Addenda>
<posadas:RequestForPayment>
<posadas:Hoteleria cajero="210" folio="539809" importeaPagar="         200.00" propina="     18.00" > 
</posadas:Hoteleria>
</posadas:RequestForPayment>
</cfdi:Addenda>
</cfdi:Comprobante>}
    for $z in //tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital,
    $x in //cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto[(@cantidad>0 and      @importe > 0)],
    $y in c//cfdi:ExpedidoEn
    return 
      <Factura>
        <Desc>{$x/@descripcion}</Desc>
        <Cantidad>{$x/@cantidad}</Cantidad>
        <Valor>{$x/@valorUnitario}</Valor>
        <CP>{$y/@codigoPostal}</CP>
        <UUID>{$z/@UUID}</UUID>
        <Fecha>{$z/@FechaTimbrado}</Fecha>
      </Factura>
```

Now what I expected was for it to return two  sets per XML in the pack I have, so I would have 2k of  here. Nevertheless I received like 200k sets cause it mixes every $z with every $x and every $y in each possible way. I want it to respect each XML, if it takes data from an XML, all the other data must be from the same XML.

I hope I made myself clear enough, thank you for your help.

Comment: In the future, make sure your code samples comply with MCVE rules -- that means, in part, that they need to be *verifiable* -- ie. they need to create your actual problem. Something that isn't valid XML but is pseudocode can't be run through an XQuery processor by someone who wants to test that their fix worked. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more.

Comment: Anyhow, right now, your code is very much *not* clear enough. It's using "element" and "attribute" interchangeably in the example, yet the queries only look for elements, not attributes. For instance, one thing that might be a possible fix would be to make your queries for $y and $z relative to the location of $x across a different axis, but that makes an assumption about your data's layout that the question's content is insufficient to either confirm or deny.

Comment: If the only available option is to index over the three collections simultaneously rather than doing a cross product (x[1], y[1], z[1]; x[2], y[2], z[2]; etc), that's possible as well, but it's considerably more error-prone should your data have contents that don't comply with the structure you expect, so we'd want to know more about the structure of your data to know if it's the only option.

Comment: Ill attach an original xml and the code I used, thank you!

Comment: So -- I had to change that a little to run, passing the XML as a context item and removing the external document contents, but it doesn't yield results as reformed, apparently because there is no `cfdi:ExpeditoEn` in the document as given.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/72a194a1020ff6616a9f655e8efebf1f for the standalone form. BTW, once you've edited it enough that it really does reproduce the bug when someone else runs it, you might also consider trimming down contents which aren't necessary for such reproduction (the "minimal" part of "MCVE").

Comment: ...as-edited, this still isn't runnable by anyone who isn't you -- it refers to `collection('foo')`, but folks who aren't you won't have that collection; that's part of why the gist I gave you above as an example of how to modify this into a MCVE (well, a CVE, it still isn't "minimal") declares the document to be queried against as a context item.

Comment: collection('foo') depends on where you store the data, so I really cant change it for you to just run it, or I think so. I trimmed it, if you want I can trimm it more. There might've been a typo in cdfi:ExpedidoEn since you wrote cfdi:ExpeditoEn?

Comment: But someone doesn't need to store the data anywhere at all -- you can embed it into the document as a context item so that it doesn't have to be stored in the database whatsoever; the sample I gave you **shows you how to do that**.

Comment: I hope it works now, sorry for all the hustle. Kinda new at this! :)

Comment: NP, this is very helpful -- I'll dig into the problem after lunch, and hope to have a solution for you then.

Comment: I found the answer, I hope you agree with it. Thank you so much though! I'm posting another one if you're interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer, for anybody interested in how to do it, I will post the code:

```
for $x in //cfdi:Comprobante,
    $y in $x//cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto,
    $z in $x//cfdi:Complemento/tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital,
    $w in $x//cfdi:ExpedidoEn
return 
  <Factura>
    <Desc>{$y/@descripcion}</Desc>
    <Cantidad>{$y/@cantidad}</Cantidad>
    <Valor>{$y/@valorUnitario}</Valor>
    <Fecha>{$z/@FechaTimbrado}</Fecha>
    <Lugar>{$w/@codigoPostal}</Lugar>
    <UUID>{$z/@UUID}</UUID>       
  </Factura>
```

Thus, instead of having `$w`, `$y` and `$z` all searching from the root of the document (ie. `//cfdi:ExpedidoEn`), they're searching from their parent (`$x//cfdi:ExpedidoEn`).

Comment: Yup, that's a perfectly good answer. Might trim it down, if the only code that changed is the query itself.

Comment: It was, made no changes in the XML whatsoever.